# Script for autologon

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

I have an AD server enviroment, and some of the users need to autologon directly.

I know that I can change some values on `RegEdit` to do so, and I am trying to create a script or `.reg` file to change those automatically, *so I won't need to input the data manually in the future and my co-workers can do the same thing without asking me*.

So far I have the following line:

```
reg add Regedt32.exe "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v AutoAdminLogon /t REG_SZ /d 1
```

…but it won't work, I think it is because I need an administrative login to make this modifications.

Is there any way to prompt a user and password box when I try to run the script or a reg file? or if someone have a better sintax for me to use this?

Comment: Are you looking for [`runas`](http://ss64.com/nt/runas.html)?

Comment: The command should be `REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /V AutoAdminLogon /D 1 /F >NUL`

Comment: with this modification on the command it should do the autologon ?

Comment: Did you try it? Also depending upon your Operating Systems the local machine keys may be subject to permissions, you may therefore need to see if the advice above mine helps you too!

Comment: I never used runas, but i've heard of it, it's syntax lets you run something on another user, but how can I combine it with the [.reg] ?

Comment: From cmdline do `runas /?` and you will be amazed :)

Comment: if I don't miss nothing, many users may change autolog feature, are all of them *admin* or know *admin credentials?* Not a good idea but, test the script, it may be an starting point for you.

Answer (score 1):

supposed you have admin rights,

autologon.cmd

```
@echo off
set "_key_logon_=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon"

echo User to be Autologged 
set/P user="*     user: "
set "psCmd=powershell -Command "$pwd = read-host '* password' -AsSecureString; $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pwd); [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%P in (`%psCmd%`) do set "pass=%%P"

:setReg
reg add "%_key_logon_%" /V "AutoAdminLogon" /T REG_SZ /D "1" /F >NUL 2>&1
reg add "%_key_logon_%" /V "DefaultUserName" /T REG_SZ /D "%user%" /F >NUL 2>&1
reg add "%_key_logon_%" /V "DefaultPassword" /T REG_SZ /D "%pass%" /F >NUL 2>&1
exit/B 0
```

you can **hardcore** *username and password* instead of asking, but **sure it is NOT a good idea**

Another one if not running admin, but knowing admin credentials

```
@echo off
set "_key_logon_=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon"
set "user=%~1"
set "pass=%~2"
if "%user%" neq "" if "%pass%" neq "" goto :setReg

rem admin credentials
echo Sign in with your ADM ID  
set/P adminUser="*     user: "
call:getPass adminPass

rem test credentials
call :askIsAdmin || (echo Invalid credentials or not enough rights. & exit /B)

rem user credentials
echo/  
echo User to be Autologged 
set/P user="*     user: "
call:getPass pass

rem now elevate
call :elevateScript && exit /B 0

:setReg
reg add "%_key_logon_%" /V "AutoAdminLogon" /T REG_SZ /D "1" /F >NUL 2>&1
reg add "%_key_logon_%" /V "DefaultUserName" /T REG_SZ /D "%user%" /F >NUL 2>&1
reg add "%_key_logon_%" /V "DefaultPassword" /T REG_SZ /D "%pass%" /F >NUL 2>&1
exit/B 0

rem helper pass reader
:getPass
SetLocal
set "psCmd=powershell -Command "$pwd = read-host '* password' -AsSecureString; $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pwd); [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%P in (`%psCmd%`) do set "pwd=%%P"
if "%pwd%" EQU "" EndLocal & exit/B 1
EndLocal & set "%1=%pwd%"
doskey /listsize=0 >NUL 2>&1 & doskey /listsize=50 >NUL 2>&1        & rem clear keyboard buffer
exit/B 0

rem helper admin rights tester
:askIsAdmin
set "psCmd=powershell -Command "$p='%adminPass%'^|convertto-securestring -asplaintext -force;$c=new-object -typename system.management.automation.pscredential^('%adminUser%',$p^);start-process 'powershell' '-Command "write-host ^([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent^(^)^).IsInRole^([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator^)"' -credential $c -passthru -wait;""
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%A in (`%psCmd%`) do @set "result=%%A"
echo %result% | find /I "true">NUL 2>&1 && set/A ret=0
EndLocal & exit/B %ret%
exit/B 1

rem helper elevate script
:elevateScript
SetLocal
set "_vbs_file_=%TEMP%\runadmin.vbs"
echo set oWS ^= CreateObject^("wScript.Shell"^)>"%_vbs_file_%"
echo strcmd="C:\Windows\system32\runas.exe /user:%COMPUTERNAME%\%adminUser% " + """%~f0 %user% %pass%""">>"%_vbs_file_%"
echo oWS.run strcmd, 2, false>>"%_vbs_file_%"
echo wScript.Sleep 100>>%_vbs_file_%
echo oWS.SendKeys "%adminPass%{ENTER}">>%_vbs_file_%
if exist "%TEMP%\runadmin.vbs" (set "_spawn_=%TEMP%\runadmin.vbs") else (set "_spawn_=runadmin.vbs")
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
start /B /WAIT cmd /C "cls & "%_spawn_%" & del /F /Q "%_spawn_%" 2>NUL"
EndLocal
exit/B 0
```

NOTE: take into account that password is stored plain text in *DefaultPassword* registry key